# Can I make Scala prefer an implicit conversion to a Java 8 Lambda?

Tags: scala, java-8, implicit-conversion

I am writing a Scala wrapper for the kafka-streams library. The basic approach is to provide implicit conversions from kafka-streams classes like `KStream` to a rich `KStreamOps` class.

For example, `KStream` provides the following `map` signature:

```
<K1, V1> KStream<K1, V1> map(KeyValueMapper<K, V, KeyValue<K1, V1>> mapper)
```

where `KeyValueMapper` is a SAM with signature (from the Scala perspective) `(K, V) => KeyValue[K1, V1]`.

Here's a minimal implementation of `KStreamOps` providing a `map` method:

```
class KStreamOps[K, V](underlying: KStream[K, V]) {
  def map[K1, V1](f: (K, V) => (K1, V1)): KStream[K1, V1] =
    underlying.map { (k, v) =>
      val tuple = f(k, v)
      KeyValue.pair(tuple._1, tuple._2)
    }
}
```

Notice that `map` here expects a function that returns a `Tuple2` and handles converting that to the `kafka-streams`-specific `KeyValue` type so that the user doesn't need to interact with `KeyValue` directly.

I provide an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def ops[K, V](kstream: KStream[K, V]): KStreamOps[K, V] = new KStreamOps[K, V](kstream)
```

But when I try to use my new `map` in code like the following:

```
val inputStream: KStream[Int, String] = builder.stream(inputTopic)
stream.map{ (k, v) => (k, v) }
```

I receive the following compilation error:

```
[error] KStreamOpsTest.scala:47: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (Int, String)
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[Int,String]
[error]       stream.map((k, v) => (k, v))
[error]                            ^
[error] KStreamOpsTest.scala:47: Could not derive subclass of org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[Int,String,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[Int,String]]
[error]  (with SAM `def method apply(x$1: Int, x$2: String)org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[Int,String]`)
[error]  based on: ((k: Int, v: String) => scala.Tuple2(k, v)).
[error]       stream.map((k, v) => (k, v))
```

So, the compiler is trying to use the `KStream#map` using the SAM that expects `KeyValue` to be returned instead of my `KStreamOps#map` that expects the output of the function to be a `Tuple2`.

If I rename my method to `KStreamOps#map1` and call `stream.map1`, the implicit conversion works as expected and the code compiles.

Why isn't the compiler able to recognize that there's an implicit conversion that would get a method that takes a function of the correct signature? Is function return type not considered? Will the SAM always win?

I'm testing this with Scala 2.11.8 with the `-Xexperimental` flag turned on.

Comment: Compiler won't look for implicit conversion to something that has a `map` method if such method already exists on the original object. This is simply how algorithm works. Not sure how to go around this, except for renaming or creating your own wrapper class that is created explicitly, not implicitly.

Comment: I'd like to more completely understand what determines uniqueness of method signatures. I assume a `map` method that takes two arguments instead of one, for example, would not be confused with the existing `map` method and would trigger looking for an implicit conversion. I also assume that a `map(x: Int)` that takes in a non-function type would be distinct. Is that true? Is the particular problem here one of type erasure, that the signature compiles down to `map(f: Function)` and thus isn't able to distinguish the function parameter and return types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Łukasz suggests, creating an explicit wrapper seems like the way to go here. And I will likely provide an implicit conversion from my wrapper type back to `KStream`:

```
implicit def unwrap[K, V](wrapped: WrappedKStream[K, V]): KStream[K, V] = wrapped.underlying
```

This way we'll have both the methods of `KStream` and of the wrapper available, but the wrapper class methods get precedence.

The one obvious downside here is that users will need to use the wrapper type explicitly when creating the initial object.